# how to view a 3D pcd in Qt on Ubunto with PCL library?

Tags: c++, qt, 3d, visualization, point-cloud-library

I am starting to use PCL library in my project , which is in Qt in Ubuntu.
I have a PCD file and i want to see it.
all the answers I have seen so far are about using visualization library

```
 #include <pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h>
```

which gives me error in my project and according to other discussions this usage is not ment for Qt.
any help on how could i view my pcd file?
thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause!
it was because I did not have installed the visualization library!
the problem was that I had not checked the output of compiling  the PCL library and it had said that it would not compile some modules because of dependency problems.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your ".pro" file. This is how I attach Irrlicht to my Qt projects which may have something similar to what you're after. By adding the references for the include directory and the libs directly.

Hope this helps.

```
win32:INCLUDEPATH += C:\irrlicht-1.8\include
win32:LIBS += c:\irrlicht-1.8\lib\win32-gcc\libirrlicht.a
```

Comment: thanks for your help but that is not what I'm looking for since I can easily include other libraries of PCL which are in the same path and are installed all together.